# Convergence issues with this derivation of the functional equation of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

I am using Riemann's Zeta Function by H.M. Edwards as a reference for the derivation of the functional equation of the Riemann Zeta Function, as well as [this pdf](https://www.nhn.ou.edu/%7Emilton/p5013/zeta.pdf). I am not very familiar with the nuances of analytic continuation, but I have taken introductory complex analysis so far. Consider:

$$f(z)=\frac{(-x)^{s}}{e^x-1}\frac{dz}{z} \tag{1}$$

Where $s=\sigma+i\tau$. Using part of a keyhole contour defined as $\gamma_1(t)=te^{i\delta}$ where $R\leq t \leq \epsilon$, $\gamma_2(t)=\epsilon e^{i\theta}$ where $\delta\leq \theta \leq 2\pi-\delta$, and $\gamma_3(t)=te^{-i\delta}$ where $\epsilon \leq t \leq R$. We want to integrate over $C=\gamma_1\sqcup\gamma_2\sqcup\gamma_3$ (in an opposite direction relative to how keyhole contours are done normally), and taking the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ and $R \to \infty$. For the portion $\gamma_2$, it is important to note that it converges to 0 only if $Re(s)= \sigma >1$ since:
$$\Biggl| \int_{\delta}^{2\pi-\delta}\frac{e^{sLog(-\epsilon e^{i\theta})}}{e^{\epsilon e^{i \theta}}-1}idt\Biggl| \leq \int_{\delta}^{2\pi-\delta} \bigg|\frac{\epsilon^{\sigma-1}*e^{\tau\pi}}{1+\frac{\epsilon}{2!} + \frac{\epsilon^2}{3!}+...}\bigg|d\theta \tag{2}$$
After performing the integration and taking limits we obtain:
$$\int_C \frac{(-x)^{s-1}}{e^x-1}\frac{dz}{z}=2i\sin(\pi s)\Gamma(s)\zeta(s) \tag{3}$$
Which can be rewritten using the Gamma reflection property to obtain:
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{2 \pi i} \int_C \frac{(-x)^{s-1}}{e^x-1}\frac{dz}{z} \tag{4}$$
Edwards says that $(3)$ is infact convergent for all $s\neq 1$, but I am not sure how he comes to that conclusion since $(2)$ shows that $\sigma>1$ must be true in order to verify convergence. Ignoring that we can then close the contour with the circle $\gamma_4(t)=Re^{i-\theta}$ where $2\pi-\delta \geq \theta \geq \delta$. The integral over this circle converges to 0 provided $Re(s)<0$ (This detail is bought up in the pdf above) which I am confused by since we wanted $\sigma>1$ earlier. Ignoring that we can then apply residue theorem where the function has poles at $z=2\pi ik$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z},k \neq 0$. We must multiply one side of the equation by negative 1 since the contour C must be positively oriented. We then get:
$$\zeta(s)=\Gamma(1-s)\sum_{\substack{k\in \mathbb{Z} \\ k\neq 0}}-Res(f(z),2\pi ik)$$
Now for arbitrary k:
$$-Res(f(z),2\pi ik)=(-2\pi i n)^{s-1}$$
Using some algebra and the identity for the complex sin function we get:
$$\zeta(s)=2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})\Gamma(1-s)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{s-1}$$
The algebra that I have omitted is explained in the book. Obtaining the final functional equation involves asserting that:
$$\zeta(1-s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{s-1}$$
Though I am not sure why this assertion is valid since the sum would be divergent, though it does give the correct answer.

I am not sure how to reason out why this derivation works given that there are multiple conditions on what $Re(s)$ must be for certain parts of the derrivation. $Re(s)>1$ must be true for $(2)$ to converge to 0. But, integral around $\gamma_4$ must have $Re(s)<0$ in order to converge to 0. But Edwards says that $(3)$ Is valid for all $s$ which doesn't seem to be true because of $(2)$. Why are we allowed to say that $\zeta(1-s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{s-1}$ if the sum is clearly divergent? And how do we get the final conclusion that the formula is valid for all $s\neq 1$? Thank you.

Comment: $\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-s}$ is valid for $\Re(s)>1$ and $\zeta(1-s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{s-1}$ is valid for $\Re(s)<0$. Also $\mathcal{M}_x\left[\frac{1}{e^x-1}\right](s)=\Gamma(s)\,\zeta(s)=\Gamma(s)\,\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k^{-s}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{M}_x\left[e^{-k\,x}\right](s)$ where $\mathcal{M}_x\left[f(x)\right](s)=\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\,x^{s-1}\,dx$ is the definition of the Mellin transform.

Comment: @StevenClark I get what you mean for the first part, but how exactly does writing the identities in terms of mellin transforms fix the convergence issues?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all of your issues with the convergence, but you indicated $\zeta(1-s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{s-1}$ is divergent but it actually converges for $\Re(s)<0$, so $\zeta(s)=2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})\,\Gamma(1-s) \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{s-1}$ converges for $\Re(s)<0$. I mentioned the Mellin transform derivation of $\Gamma(s)\,\zeta(s)$ because it's a simpler related derivation.

Comment: You can also derive the zeta functional equation as $\zeta (s)=s \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \mathcal{M}_x\left[\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\sin (2 k \pi x)}{k}\right](-s)=2^s \pi ^{s-1} \sin \left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\, \Gamma(1-s) \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k^{s-1}$ $=2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin \left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\, \Gamma(1-s)\, \zeta (1-s)$ where $\lfloor x\rfloor=x-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (2 \pi k x)}{k}\right)$ is the Fourier series for $\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Comment: Also note the Fourier series for $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is an analytic formula for $\sum_{n=1}^x \theta(x-n)$ (where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function) and $\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty s \mathcal{M}_x[\theta (x-n)](-s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ which is valid for $\Re(s)>1$.